# Can you display multiple maps on the same page with directions using Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create multiple maps on the same page with different transit directions in each one.

I've been able to iteratively create multiple Google maps, but I can't get different directions to appear in each.

I’ve created a number of divs that hold the maps and gave them IDs `map-canvas1`, `map-canvas2`, `map-canvas3`…etc. After creating the maps with the below function, how would I then show different transit directions in each one? With the code as it is now, no directions appear in any of the maps (although each of the maps do show up).

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var coordinates;

function initialize(){

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++){

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();       

        var latitude = arrayOfObjects[i].latitude;
        var longitude = arrayOfObjects[i].longitude;

        coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,       
            center: coordinates
        };

        var numString = i.toString();
        var thisMapID = "map-canvas" + numString;

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(thisMapID), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calcRoute();
    };
}

var startingLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.768211, -73.957721);

function calcRoute(){

    var request = {
        origin: startingLocation,
        destination: coordinates,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);          
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should be getting javascript errors like "coordinates is undefined" (and "arrayOf Objects is undefined" but I suspect you left that out on purpose), you will probably need to pass that into the calcRoute function, and/or use map[i].getCenter() to retrieve them.

Comment: I did leave out the `arrayOfObjects` object since this is part of a much larger codebase. `arrayOfObjects` is a global variable though and available to both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique [DirectionsRenederer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) needs to be associated with each map.  Note that the DirectionsService is subject to a quota and rate limits, if you have lots of these maps you will have to check the return status and handle OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors appropriately (you may want to handle errors in general, so the service will tell you *why* some maps don't show a route).

[working example (with 2 maps)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directionsMultipleMaps.html)

```
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = [];
var map = [];
var coordinates;

function initialize(){

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++){
        directionsService[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsDisplay[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();       

        var latitude = arrayOfObjects[i].latitude;
        var longitude = arrayOfObjects[i].longitude;

        coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,       
            center: coordinates
        };

        var numString = i.toString();
        var thisMapID = "map-canvas" + numString;

        map[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(thisMapID), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay[i].setMap(map[i]);

        calcRoute(i);
    };
}

var startingLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.768211, -73.957721);

function calcRoute(index){
    var request = {
        origin: startingLocation,
        destination: map[index].getCenter(),
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    };

    directionsService[index].route(request, function(response, status){
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay[index].setDirections(response);          
        } else { alert("Directions request failed: " + status); }
    }); 
}
```