# How to show two routes on the same map?

Tags: google-maps

How to show two routes on the same map? 
Example: A->B y C->D.
Using Google Maps API.

```
      function calcRoute1() {
        var start = 'Huanchaco-Trujillo';
        var end = 'Lince-Lima';
        var request1 = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request1, function(response1, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response1);
          }
        });
      }

      function calcRoute2() {
        var start = 'Chiclayo-Lambayeque';
        var end = 'Tacna-Tacna';
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Yes.  Use two separate instances of the directionsRenderer (and probably two different instances of the directionsService). If the bounds of the two routes are very different you may need to manually calculate a bounds that will show both ([google.maps.LatLngBounds.union](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds))

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366537/can-you-display-multiple-maps-on-the-same-page-with-directions-using-google-maps/20366832#20366832) (multiple sets of directions on different maps, but can put them all on the same map)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    var directionsService1 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    function calcRoute1() {
        var start = 'Huanchaco-Trujillo';
        var end = 'Lince-Lima';
        var request1 = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService1.route(request1, function(response1, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay1.setDirections(response1);
        directionsDisplay1.setMap(map);
          }
        });
      }

      var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      function calcRoute2() {
        var start = 'Chiclayo-Lambayeque';
        var end = 'Tacna-Tacna';
        var request2 = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService2.route(request2, function(response2, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay2.setDirections(response2);
        directionsDisplay2.setMap(map);
          }
        });
      }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directions2Routes.html)