# Multiple google maps on same page in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have an application that utilises localstorage and within that storage are multiple lat and lon values that I wish to display on a map. Now I have managed to put out all the values on the map for the first map within my loop, but how would I manage to do that for the remaining maps?

My function to display results:

```
function displayRides(){
// similar to the finish function, except it handles multiple rides
    var localLat;
    var localLon;
    var marker;
    var path = [];
    var integer;

    //pagination variables
    var start = 0;

    // add pagination buttons to page
    $(".content").append("<div><input type='submit' value='previous'/><div>Ride: "+ (start + 1) +"</div><input type='submit' value='next'/></div><br />");

    // this will display all the rides on the page
    var ride = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rides"));

    // test this later
    if(ride == undefined || ride == null){ console.log("there are no rides available")}

    // loop each ride
    $.each(ride, function (i) {

        var time = this[1].time;
        var rideDist = this[2].totalDistance.toFixed(2);

        $.each(ride[i], function (j) {
        if(this.date != undefined){
        var integer = j;

            localLat = this.info[j].data.lat;
            localLon = this.info[j].data.lon;

            //push to path in order to draw path on map
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(localLat, localLon));


                    $(".content").append("<div><h2>Date: " + this.date + "</h2></div><br />");
                    $(".content").append("<div><h2>Time: " + time + "</h2></div><br />");
                    $(".content").append("<div><h2>Distance: " + rideDist + "</h2></div><br />");

                    // add map and draw route
                    $(".content").append("<div id='mapDiv'></div><br />");

                    //add delete button
                    $(".content").append("<div><button><h2>Delete Ride</h2></button</div><br />");
                }
            });
    });

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(localLat, localLon); 

    //specify map options
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }; 

    //create the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), myOptions);


    // draw path
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FFAF04',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

My local storage:

rides:

```
[[{"date":"13/4/2014","info":[{"id":1,"data":{"speed":0,"distance":0,"lat":53.56734,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":2,"data":{"speed":26.286480658774042,"distance":0.4381080109795674,"lat":53.5634,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":3,"data":{"speed":12.943089461363288,"distance":0.21571815768938812,"lat":53.56534,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":4,"data":{"speed":0.6271393863606013,"distance":0.010452323106010021,"lat":53.565434,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":5,"data":{"speed":0.6271393863037149,"distance":0.010452323105061915,"lat":53.56534,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":6,"data":{"speed":12.943089461410691,"distance":0.21571815769017819,"lat":53.5634,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":7,"data":{"speed":19.61478506003074,"distance":0.3269130843338457,"lat":53.56634,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":8,"data":{"speed":19.614785060068666,"distance":0.3269130843344778,"lat":53.5634,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":9,"data":{"speed":196.14785060101815,"distance":3.2691308433503026,"lat":53.534,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":10,"data":{"speed":4.003017359194785,"distance":0.06671695598657974,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":11,"data":{"speed":7.161421261342885,"distance":0.11935702102238141,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.44534}},{"id":12,"data":{"speed":7.161421261294456,"distance":0.11935702102157426,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":13,"data":{"speed":0.31960717258462806,"distance":0.0053267862097438005,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.4434534}},{"id":14,"data":{"speed":0.3196071725800495,"distance":0.005326786209667492,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.443534}},{"id":15,"data":{"speed":7.161421261342885,"distance":0.11935702102238141,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.44534}},{"id":16,"data":{"speed":31.960717240968293,"distance":0.5326786206828049,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.4534}},{"id":17,"data":{"speed":319.6071555364947,"distance":5.326785925608245,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.534}},{"id":18,"data":{"speed":76.92778075556625,"distance":1.2821296792594374,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.5534}},{"id":19,"data":{"speed":7.692778099085561,"distance":0.12821296831809267,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.55534}}]},{"time":"00:00:15"},{"totalDistance":12.51865476992974}],[{"date":"13/4/2014","info":[{"id":1,"data":{"speed":0,"distance":0,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":2,"data":{"speed":67.1172577226746,"distance":1.1186209620445766,"lat":53.52334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":3,"data":{"speed":6.711725772243759,"distance":0.11186209620406266,"lat":53.522334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":4,"data":{"speed":6.711725772310127,"distance":0.11186209620516879,"lat":53.52334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":5,"data":{"speed":67.11725772264613,"distance":1.1186209620441023,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":6,"data":{"speed":0.40030173590525686,"distance":0.006671695598420948,"lat":53.53334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":7,"data":{"speed":0.4003017359716243,"distance":0.006671695599527071,"lat":53.5334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":8,"data":{"speed":133.03361023752902,"distance":2.2172268372921504,"lat":53.55334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":9,"data":{"speed":6.631665425024785,"distance":0.11052775708374642,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.55534}},{"id":10,"data":{"speed":7.688974523077317,"distance":0.12814957538462196,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.5534}},{"id":11,"data":{"speed":76.8897449949351,"distance":1.281495749915585,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.534}},{"id":12,"data":{"speed":37.25585591042068,"distance":0.6209309318403446,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.5434}},{"id":13,"data":{"speed":7.6889745230241635,"distance":0.12814957538373606,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.54534}},{"id":14,"data":{"speed":7.688974523077317,"distance":0.12814957538462196,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.5434}},{"id":15,"data":{"speed":37.25585591044057,"distance":0.6209309318406762,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.534}},{"id":16,"data":{"speed":37.25585591042068,"distance":0.6209309318403446,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.5434}},{"id":17,"data":{"speed":7.6889745230241635,"distance":0.12814957538373606,"lat":53.554334,"lon":-1.54534}}]},{"time":"00:00:12"},{"totalDistance":8.458950949045422}]]
```

Please note, I have tried the following with no luck:

- assigning different map ID's while looping.
- moving the mapping into the loop

**What have I done wrong that it wont let me display multiple maps?**

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to put all the points on all the maps?  Or one point on each map?  Or something else?  You say you can put all the points on the first map, the code you have posted includes only one map; what have you tried to add additional maps?  Can you provide a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I am trying to add multiple maps to a page that have multiple points on them. I thought using a loop to iterate over the points would work for multiple maps but it isn't. I will try a jsfiddle

Comment: It does work as long as you have unique maps, unique map variables and add the points to the map you want them on.

Comment: is that possible in a  loop?

Comment: If you write it correctly, somewhere in SO is an example of multiple maps on a page with a single marker on each; can't find it right now, but I remember making it.

Comment: [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366537/can-you-display-multiple-maps-on-the-same-page-with-directions-using-google-maps/20366832#20366832) (not the one I was remembering...)