# Google Maps dynamically generated showing only one map instead of multiple

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I have a button search, which dynamically shows hotels. I want next to them I want to show a map.
For the time being I have the same lat and long for all hotels so I expect to see the same map. However, currently I see only one map generated for the first hotel. The rest are blank. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```html
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    function initMap() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/accommodations')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.dir(data)
                data.forEach(function (hotel) {
                    console.log(hotel);
                    const coords = {
                        lat: parseFloat(hotel.lat),
                        lng: parseFloat(hotel.lng)
                    };
                    console.log(coords);

                    const map = new google.maps.Map(
                        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: coords});
                    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: coords, map: map});
                })
            })
    }
</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

                                document.getElementById('showAll').addEventListener('click', showAll);

                                function showAll() {
                                    // window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

                                    fetch('http://localhost:8080/accommodations')
                                        .then(response => {
                                            return response.json()
                                        })
                                        .then((data) => {
                                            console.dir(data) 

                                            let output = '<h2 style="padding-left: 27px"> Search Results </h2>'

                                            data.forEach(function (hotel) {
                                                console.dir(hotel) 
                                                initMap();

                                                output += `
                                           <div class="col-lg-3 px-0" id="map"></div> `;
                                            });

                                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output
                                        })
                                }
```

Comment: why are you running code snippets if you can't display the result...

Comment: HTML ids need to be unique.  Looks to me like all your map `<div>` elements have the same id ("map").  Hard to tell for sure as you didn't provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Related question: [Can you display multiple maps on the same page with directions using Google Maps JavaScript API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366537/can-you-display-multiple-maps-on-the-same-page-with-directions-using-google-maps)

Comment: related question: [Google Maps. Multiple maps with multiple markers with content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652143/google-maps-multiple-maps-with-multiple-markers-with-content)

Comment: [3 maps on one page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_3maps.html)